# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String for (Using map to update the details from Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Currently, I'm trying to use to update the details from my Firebase Database.However, it gives the classcastexception error. Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank you

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.google.online_mobile_flexi_parking, PID: 21533
              java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                  at com.google.online_mobile_flexi_parking.ChangeEmailPassword$8$1.onDataChange(ChangeEmailPassword.java:243)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakg.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalg.zzcxk(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalj$1.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5028)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

243 line is  phoneAcc.set_IdentityCard(map.get("_IdentityCard"));

ChangeEmailPassword.java

```
public class ChangeEmailPassword extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnChangeEmail, btnChangePassword,
            changeEmail, changePassword, back, btnChangePhone, btnChangeCarPlate, changePhone,
            changeCarPlate, signOut;

    private EditText oldEmail, newEmail, password, newPassword, oldPhone, newPhone, confirmPassword;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    FirebaseUser user;
    private String txtPhone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_email_password);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //get firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //get current user
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    // user auth state is changed - user is null
                    // launch login activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, TestUser.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        btnChangeEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_email_button);
        btnChangePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_password_button);
        btnChangePhone=(Button)findViewById(R.id.change_phone_button);
        changeEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeEmail);
        changePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changePass);
        changePhone=(Button) findViewById(R.id.changePhone);
        //signOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out);
        back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnback1);

        oldEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.old_email);
        newEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        newPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
        confirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.confirmpassword);
        oldPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.old_phone);
        newPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_phone);


        oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        confirmPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        oldPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        newPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if (progressBar != null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, TestUser.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnChangeEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                newEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                confirmPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                changeEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                changePhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                oldPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                newPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        changeEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (user != null && !newEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    user.updateEmail(newEmail.getText().toString().trim())
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Email address is updated. Please sign in with new email id!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, MainActivity.class));
                                        finish();

                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Failed to update email!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                } else if (newEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    newEmail.setError("Enter email");
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        btnChangePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                newPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                confirmPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                changePassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                changePhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                oldPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                newPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        changePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (user != null && !newPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    if (newPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() < 6) {
                        newPassword.setError("Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters");
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (!(newPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals(confirmPassword.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                        newPassword.setError("Password are not matching");
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        user.updatePassword(newPassword.getText().toString().trim())
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Password is updated, sign in with new password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, MainActivity.class));
                                            finish();

                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Failed to update password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                } else if (newPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    newPassword.setError("Enter password");
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        btnChangePhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                confirmPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                changePhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                oldPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                newPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


        changePhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtPhone = newPhone.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!txtPhone.equals("")) {
                    mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            Account phoneAcc=new Account();
                            Map<String,String> map=(Map)dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            phoneAcc.set_FullName(map.get("_FullName"));
                            phoneAcc.set_CarPlate1(map.get("_CarPlate1"));

                            phoneAcc.set_IdentityCard(map.get("_IdentityCard"));

                            phoneAcc.set_Phone(txtPhone);
                            mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).setValue(phoneAcc);
                            Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Phone is updated, sign in with new password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    } else if (txtPhone.equals("")) {
                    newPhone.setError("Enter phone number");
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Account.java

```
  public class Account {
        private String _Phone;
        private String _IdentityCard;
        private String _FullName;
        private String _CarPlate1;
        private String _CarPlate2;
        private String _CarPlate3;

    public Account(){}

    public Account(String fullname, String phone, String carplate1, String identitycard)
    {
        this._Phone=phone;
        this._CarPlate1=carplate1;
        this._FullName=fullname;
        this._IdentityCard=identitycard;
    }

    public Account(String carplate1,String carplate2,String carplate3)
    {
        this._CarPlate1=carplate1;
        this._CarPlate2=carplate2;
        this._CarPlate3=carplate3;
    }
    public void set_Phone(String _Phone) {
        this._Phone = _Phone;
    }

    public String get_Phone() {
        return _Phone;
    }

    public String get_IdentityCard() {
        return _IdentityCard;
    }

    public void set_IdentityCard(String _IdentityCard){this._IdentityCard=_IdentityCard;}

    public String get_FullName() {
        return _FullName;
    }

    public void set_FullName(String _FullName){ this._FullName=_FullName;}

    public void set_CarPlate1(String _CarPlate1) {
        this._CarPlate1 = _CarPlate1;
    }

    public String get_CarPlate1() {
        return _CarPlate1;
    }

    public void set_CarPlate2(String _CarPlate2) {
        this._CarPlate2 = _CarPlate2;
    }

    public String get_CarPlate2() {
        return _CarPlate2;
    }

    public void set_CarPlate3(String _CarPlate3) {
        this._CarPlate3 = _CarPlate3;
    }

    public String get_CarPlate3() {
        return _CarPlate3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means you can't cast Long type to String directly.Try add ""  like

`long l = 123;
String str = "" + l;`

Comment: but I don't have long type for both classes

Answer (score 1):

**When you are assigning the long value into string then**

```
long var = 1;
String value = ""+var;
```

**insted of assigning like**

```
String value = var;
```

**It will work.**

Comment: but I don't have long type for both classes

Comment: Why wouldn't `var as String` work? I tried it in a different context and had to replace it with `"" + var`.